# Component getList cache not loading/saving

Tags: component, custom-component, cache, model

I've built a custom component, and I'm trying to make it a bit faster, and while I was rooting through model core files I saw that their `getItems()` uses a caching to reduce DB queries:

```
$store = $this->getStoreId();
if (isset($this->cache[$store]))
{
    return $this->cache[$store];
}

try
{
    // Load the list items and add the items to the internal cache.
    $this->cache[$store] = $this->_getList($this->_getListQuery(), $this->getStart(), $this->getState('list.limit'));
}
```

So I'm attempting to duplicate this for my component. Code is practically the same, but whenever I check `isset($this->cache[$store])` it is always unset. I'm unsure if I'm having a problem fetching `$this->cache[$store]` or saving to it.

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error logs?

Comment: Just poked around the log files and turned on Development mode for Error Reporting, still no messages.

Comment: Which version of Joomla? Which PHP version? Which cache handler? What's the cache time?

Comment: This is all running on Joomla! 3.7.5 and PHP 5.6.30. The cache handler is set to File with a cache time of 15 minutes.

Comment: Print out the $store variable and see what it is getting set to or if it is getting set at all.

Comment: which model class are you extending? and post the whole code of your model class. It will be helpful for us

Comment: `$store` contains the md5 hash created from `$id.':'.$this->getState('list.start').':'.$this->getState('list.limit').':'.$this->getState('list.ordering').':'.$this->getState('list.direction');`. I made sure that it wasn't randomly changing everytime I load pages, it stays consistent between refreshes and updates as I change pagination values.

Also, it's an extension of JModelList, which itself extends JModelLegacy

Answer (score 2):

In your component controller, check the display function:

```
public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)
{    
    //...

    parent::display($cachable, $safeurlparams);

    return $this;
}
```

Change it to:

```
parent::display(true, $safeurlparams);
```

And test again.

Comment: I tried forcing `$cachable` to true to no avail, but I did however see a spot where I might be able to investigate to help fix the problem. Will report back once I've had time to poke around and what not.